Max Product Finder with heap
task:
Max Product Finder
Create a maxProductFinderK() function that takes in a list of numbers and an integer k, and returns the largest product that can be attained from any k integers in the list. You may presume that the length of the list of integers is greater than or equal to k.
For example, maxProductFinderK([-8, 6, -7, 3, 2, 1, -9], 2) should return 72 and maxProductFinderK([-8, 6, -7, 3, 2, 1, -9], 3) should return 432.
I get on it 4/5  ): ,and i dont even know what is missing.
Code:
class MaxHeap {
    constructor() {
        this.heap = [];
    }
    get size() {
        return this.heap.length;
    }
    getParent(index) {
        return Math.floor((index - 1) / 2);
    }
    getLeft(index) {
        return 2 * index + 1;
    }
    getRight(index) {
        return 2 * index + 2;
    }
    add(value) {
        this.heap.push(value);
        this.heapifyUp();
    }
    heapifyUp() {
        let index = this.heap.length - 1;
        while (index > 0) {
            let parentIndex = this.getParent(index);
            if (this.heap[parentIndex] < this.heap[index]) {
                [this.heap[parentIndex], this.heap[index]] = [this.heap[index], this.heap[parentIndex]];
                index = parentIndex;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    remove() {
        if (this.heap.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (this.heap.length === 1) {
            return this.heap.pop();
        }
        let max = this.heap[0];
        this.heap[0] = this.heap.pop();
        this.heapifyDown(0);
        return max;
    }
    heapifyDown(index) {
        let left = this.getLeft(index);
        let right = this.getRight(index);
        let largest = index;
        if (left < this.heap.length && this.heap[left] > this.heap[largest]) {
            largest = left;
        }
        if (right < this.heap.length && this.heap[right] > this.heap[largest]) {
            largest = right;
        }
        if (largest !== index) {
            [this.heap[index], this.heap[largest]] = [this.heap[largest], this.heap[index]];
            this.heapifyDown(largest);
        }
    }
    printHeap() {
        let arr = [];
        while (this.heap.length > 0) {
            let max = this.remove();
            arr.push(max);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
function maxProductFinderK(numbers, size) {
  if(numbers.length === 0 || size === 0){
     return 0
  }
  if(size === numbers.length){
    return numbers.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator * currentValue, 1);
  }
    let positive = new MaxHeap();
    let negative = new MaxHeap();
    for (let n of numbers) {
        if (n < 0) {
            negative.add(Math.abs(n));
        } else {
            positive.add(n);
        }
    }
    let k = size;
    positive = positive.printHeap();
    negative = negative.printHeap();

    console.log(positive);
    console.log(negative);



    let result = 1;
    while (negative.length >= 2 && positive.length >= 2 && k>=2) {
        let negativeProduct = negative[0] * negative[1]
        let positiveProduct = positive[0] * positive[1];
        if (negativeProduct > positiveProduct) {
            result *= negativeProduct;
            negative.shift();
            negative.shift();
        } else {
            result *= positiveProduct;
            positive.shift();
            positive.shift();
        }
        k -= 2;
    }

    while (positive.length >= 2 && k>=2) {
        result *= (positive[0] * positive[1]);
        positive.shift();
        positive.shift();
        k -= 2;
    }
    while (negative.length >= 2 && k>=2) {
        result *= (negative[0] * negative[1]);
        negative.shift();
        negative.shift();
        k -= 2;
    }

    // console.log(k)

    if (k === 1) {
        if (positive.length > 0) {
            result *= positive[0];
        } else {
            result *= negative[0];
        }
    }
    console.log("result is "+ result);
    return result
}


Is there a link to the question to test? If there is, add it to your question.

I see you build the heaps in a slow way, and are actually sorting the input by grabbing values from the heap. The heap plays no role anymore during the main part of the algorithm. So you are sorting the input in a rather slow way (the native sort would be faster). Are you sure your test case fails because of a wrong output, or did you get a timeout?

@trincot this is task in codecademy after you learn heap there were 3 question 2 in leetcode and this one. I know that sorting is better but thats what they ask for :)

I'm sure they are not asking you to build a heap only to fully empy it immediately afterwards.

But my question remains....

You could simply sort the array and check the first two values as product against the last two items as product and take the ones with the larger product. Finally if only one item k is left take the largest value (at end of sorted array).


function maxProductFinderK(values, k) {
    let product = 1;
    values.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    while (k) {
        if (k === 1) {
            const value = values.at(-1);
            if (value < 0) return; // or throw error
            product *= value;
            break;
        }
        const fn = values[0] * values[1] > values.at(-1) * values.at(-2)
            ? 'shift'
            : 'pop';
        product *= values[fn]() * values[fn]();
        k -= 2;
    }
    return product;
}

console.log(maxProductFinderK([-8, 6, -7, 3, 2, 1, -9], 2)); //  72
console.log(maxProductFinderK([-8, 6, -7, 3, 2, 1, -9], 3)); // 432



